# how to link results to a correct rows in a partitioned table kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a column of dates based on the below conditions in lst  and runs fine and I need to link it by set or upsert or whatever means to the appropirate rows to the partitioned database.

(These are partitioned tables for the corresponding days made of many columns)

```
tbp:2016.11.01 
tb:2016.11.02

lst: distinct select  b_market_order_no,instrumentID,mkt from tb  where event=`OvernightOrder
```

I get a column of dates based on the conditions in lst, now I have to link it to the appropriate rows for table, tb, in the database. What I have down for "set" command will simply add the dates blindly, I guess to each row until it is used up. Not sure how to pass the appropriate row location to set or even if that is the right way to do it. Or upsert needs to be used! Or there is totally a different needs to be implemented!

```
(`$":PATH/2016.11.02/order/b_orig_date") set select b_orig_date from tbp where ([]b_market_order_no;instrumentID;mkt) in lst
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I'm following. Are you trying to change existing rows for just b_orig_date or are these entirely new rows which need appended?

Comment: Are you trying to append the overnight orders from 2016.11.01 to 2016.11.02?

Comment: b_orig_date is a new column added to the table and needs its value  appended for day 02 based on  results from day 01 under the where conditions and results created in lst. Day 01 for b_orig_date is fully populated. So if market_Order_no is 222  in day 01 how can I upsert the date from that row into the 02 day where market_Order_no=222

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want, also for simplicity I'm referring to the table as order with appropriate date where clauses:

Edit: added .Q.par also note the 3! as need to have  b_market_order_no, instrumentID, mkt all as the keyed columns

Edit: Generalised use if you have the hdb loaded into a q process:

```
dirPath:string .Q.par[`:.;2016.11.02;`order]
(`$dirPath,"/b_orig_date") set exec b_orig_date from 
  (select b_market_order_no, instrumentID, mkt from order where date = 2016.11.02) lj 
  3!select b_market_order_no, instrumentID, mkt, b_orig_date from order where 
    date = 2016.11.01,([]b_market_order_no;instrumentID;mkt) in lst
```

Also if this is an entirely new column for 2016.11.02/order, You will need to edit `.d`

```
(`$dirPath,"/.d") set (get `$dirPath,"/.d"),`b_orig_date
```

This column may also be needed to be added throughout a hdb using dbmaint.q

https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/utils/dbmaint.q

Answer:

```
dirPath:string .Q.par[`:.;2016.11.02;`order]
(`$dirPath,"/b_orig_date") set exec b_orig_date from 
  (select b_market_order_no, instrumentID, mkt from tb) lj 
  3!select b_market_order_no, instrumentID, mkt, b_orig_date from tbp where 
  ([]b_market_order_no;instrumentID;mkt) in lst
```

Comment: Can we do this using .Q.par? I guess I need to set this for all three distinct columns (select b_market_order_no,instrumentID,mkt from order where date = 2016.11.02 lj 
  1!select b_market_order_no,instrumentID,mkt, b_orig_date from order where 
    date = 2016.11.01,([]b_market_order_no;instrumentID;mkt) in lst

Comment: Yes, and let me edit my query if b_market_order_no is not distinct and Yes you can use .Q.par.

Comment: I tried this for .Q.par seems easier to understand but got mismatch type. b_market_order_no,instrumentID,mkt are distinct for that day. " .Q.par[`$":/...../2016.11.02/order";;hsym `b_orig_date] upsert get .Q.par[`$":/..../2016.11.01/order";;hsym `b_orig_date] "

Comment: For starters, that's not how you use .Q.par and second that won't achieve what you want.  .Q.par is used to find the file location of a table for a particular partition (in this and most cases this is date) when you have a hdb which is split over multiple directories and typically more than one hard drive

Comment: please tell me how to use .Q.par correctly in this case. Thanks

Comment: .Q.par https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qpar-locate-partition

returns the location of table. (Sensitive to par.txt.)
.Q.par[directory;partition;table]
e.g. .Q.par[`:/pathToHdb/hdb;2016.11.01;`order]

Comment: Please see my edit above where I have incorporated .Q.par. Note I have used `:. as I assume you already have the hdb loaded in so should already be in the hdb directory

Comment: I do not get any errors, but when I do count(select _b_orig_date from order where date=2016.11.02) I get 0. I did reload hdb using: .daas.events.pubEventMessage[`hdbReload;`complete;`;`;] each `$"emea_hdb_tr_transactionData_",/:string[1+til 21],\:"_a"; I loaded the hdb for the two days using getTicks function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212809/discussion-between-matt-moore-and-kevbuntu).